# Error after importing old project in Android Studio 3.3.1

Tags: android, android-studio

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
}
```

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Here is a link for image. https://www.mediafire.com/view/f2gjt1i8pn4aiy3/stack.png/file

Answer (score 1):

this error is because of that your `compileSdkVersion` is different from your support libraries version. The error says that your `compileSdkVersion` is **28** so to fix this you should have something like this in your gradle :

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 28
  buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.project.sample"
       minSdkVersion 16
       targetSdkVersion 28
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
       testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}


dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

The latest `buildToolsVersion` is `28.0.3` but you can change it to your own. It should start with `28`.

Answer (score 0):

this is because SDK 28 Version is not as much stable as...27.

set compile and target version as 27.

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
  buildToolsVersion '27.0.0'
   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.project.sample"
       minSdkVersion 16
       targetSdkVersion 27
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
       testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}


dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying.. i did some misakes and now i have a different issue.